# Make new DataFrame only with rows whose ID is not contained in second DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

There are two DataFrames. One, `df1`, contains events, and one of its columns is `ID`.
The other `df2` contains just `ID`-s.

How would be best to crate `df3` which contain just rows whose `ID` is not present in `df2`.

Looks like this type of query is not supported in Spark SQL:

```
sqlContext.sql(""" SELECT * FROM table_df1
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table_df2) """)
```

Comment: Where is this type of query supported ? :)

Comment: pure select part is supported at least in Oracle, could be some other DBs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark SQL will support this type of subqueries starting from Spark version 2.0 (more information is available on [Databricks blog](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/06/17/sql-subqueries-in-apache-spark-2-0.html)).

A way to do this in older versions of Spark would be the following:

```
df3 = sqlContext.sql(
    """
    select 
     *
    from df1 left join df2 on df1.id=df2.id 
    where df2.id is null
    """
)
```